# Error while installing Silver stripe Blog module

Tags: silverstripe

I am trying to install the Silver Stripe blog module taken from https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-blog and the SS version is 3.0

When I run dev build, it shows few tables created and then error occurs and the error is

`Access level to Blog::onBeforeWrite() must be public (as in class Page) in /home/hfdev/public_html/blog/code/model/Blog.php on line 33`

Any idea how to fix this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current `master` branch of the SilverStripe blog is for SilverStripe 3.1. This will not work with SilverStripe 3.0.

For a version of the blog that will work with SilverStripe 3.0 try the `0.6` branch: 
https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-blog/tree/0.6

Comment: I will definitely try this and let you know whether it worked or not.

Comment: Thanks @3dogo.. It worked for me.. But now I want to install the comments module and I am unable to find the correct branch for SS 3.0. The one I got is [https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-comments]

Comment: Glad I could help. For the comments module I believe branch 1.1 is the one for SilverStripe 3.0 https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-comments/tree/1.1

Comment: Thanks a lot @3dogo.. The blog as well as the comments are working now. I am making some changes to these things to fit my requirements.. Thank again for your time and help.